# how to make my unsorted list fit into the div?

Tags: css

You can see the problem here:

[image]

here you can see my css-file:

`    /*logo's*/

```
#logo {

    width: 15%;

    float: left;
    margin: auto;

}
#logo li{
    list-style-type: none;
}`
```

on the picture you can see what happens to my unsorted list.

and this is the html part: `

```
                    <ul id="logo">
                        <li><img src="AR.png" alt="alfa romeo logo" /></li>
                        <li><img src="LG.png" alt="lamborghini logo" /></li>
                        <li><img src="ferrari.png" alt="ferrari logo" /></li>
                        <li><img src="ms.png" alt="maserati logo" /></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div id="tekst">

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu mollis velit. Vestibulum porttitor eros at velit placerat volutpat. Fusce ac erat arcu, vel imperdiet purus. Curabitur tellus nisi, tristique malesuada porta sit amet, scelerisque ut urna. Sed ut sapien quis est fringilla iaculis. Curabitur ac lectus ut leo lacinia dignissim. Praesent eu felis ante. Phasellus at fringilla odio.</p>

                    </div>`
```

here is the real website if you can view it:[website](https://543724.webontwerp.khleuven.be/project/anderetemp/template/)

edit: i want the ul to fit into the tanned div, but i dont want to put a fixed height.

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS and HTML in your question.

Comment: someone upvoted? seriously?

Comment: If you want to be a good asker, provide a demo too. Jsfiddle, etc.

Comment: I'm confused. you want the `<ul>` in the `<div>`... why not put the `<ul>` INSIDE the `<div>`? Or, are we missing another part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have two div's floated within you main container `div id="inhoud"` you need to either clear the floats or set the container to `overflow:auto`

```
div#inhoud {
    margin: 10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```